# Android GSON custom deserialization

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I am trying to create custom deserializationg using GSON with Kotlin. Here is the sample code, but the variable **test** is always null. Any idea why?

```
    // simple class with x property
    class TestClass(var x: Int = 1)

    // simple deserializer that always returns object with value x = 4444
    class TestClassDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<TestClass> {
        override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): TestClass {
            return TestClass(4444)
        }
    }

    // simple gson object with register adapter
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(::TestClass.javaClass, TestClassDeserializer())
        .create()

    // init object using json string
    val json = """ {"x": 9} """.trimIndent()
    val test = gson.fromJson(json, ::TestClass.javaClass)
```

Any idea why **test** is always null, and not the expected object **TestClass(4444)**. I am using latest gson version **2.8.6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line `::TestClass.javaClass` 
Type of this expression is `KFunction1<Int, TestClass>` because it is a TestClass constructor method reference.
Correct syntax is `TestClass::class.java`

Comment: Thank, I initially used TestClass::class.java and then I tried ::TestClass.javaClass. But at first it seem that it does not work with any of the two ways. But now its working!